# OS X codesign with EV token verifies, spctl reports rejected?

Tags: macos, codesign

I have an OS X app to be distributed outside the Mac app store deployed in a DMG.

When I codesign the app folder and included frameworks with the deep option, everything verifies with codesign.

However spctl tells me it is rejected?

After running macdeployqt, then codesign, when I verify the spctl utility with verbose tells me the app folder is “rejected".

```
    codesign --verbose=4 --deep -s  “Acme, Inc."   ${appFolder} my-usb-ev-token

    codesign --deep-verify --verbose=4 ${appFolder}
    ...
    myapp/MyApp.app: valid on disk
    myapp/MyApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

    spctl --verbose --assess --type execute -v "${appFolder}"
    myapp/MyApp.app: rejected
    origin=Acme, Inc.
```

The verbose option is not helpful as to the reason it was rejected?

Any clues or suggestions are much appreciated.

-Ed